# html2canvas plugin producing a transparent Image.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html2canvas

I am working on a project where user can change css properties of some elements inside a div and then on submit, I am doing an html2canvas save for that div so as to save the image. Image is saving but it is transparent. Changes are not reflected.

HTML markup:

```
<div id="mainCanvas">
    <div id="imageOne"></div>
    <span id="txtOne" class="clTxtOne">Absolute Fun</span>
    <span id="txtTwo" class="clTxtTwo">Some Text</span>
    <span id="txtThree" class="clTxtThree">Another Text</span>
    <span id="slogan">Slogan here</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mainCanvas').html2canvas({
    background  : undefined,
    logging: true,
    taintTest: false,

    onrendered: function (canvas){
        //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
        $('#capturedImage').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        //Submit the form manually
        document.getElementById("saveImageForm").submit();
    },
});
```

Output is an Transparent Image. What could be the possible issue that I am skipping or any other such thing that is not letting my code render. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate your task in JSFiddle and got it working immediately.
I used documentation from http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html.

Try writing your function like this:

```
    html2canvas($("#mainCanvas"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $('#capturedImage').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            document.getElementById("saveImageForm").submit();
        }
    });
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4yDs/) with working example...
Try changing background by hitting "Change background color" button and then press "Append new one" to generate and append to body new canvas from HTML div "mainCanvas".